# Issue configuring JWT secret with claims_map in Hasura Docker compose

Tags: jwt, hasura, hasura-jwt, hasura-docker

I am trying to set **claims_map** in HASURA_GRAPHQL_JWT_SECRET in my docker compose file
using the below config

```
HASURA_GRAPHQL_JWT_SECRET: '{"type":"HS256","key":"***************************","claims_namespace":"p-clamis-allow","claims_map":{"x-hasura-user-id":{"path":"$.user.id"}}}'
```

I get the following error:

**Invalid interpolation format for "environment" option in service "graphql-engine":"{"type":"HS256","key":"***************************","claims_namespace":"p-clamis-allow","claims_map":{"x-hasura-user-id":{"path":"$.user.id"}}}"**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace $ with $$ and things should work!

HASURA_GRAPHQL_JWT_SECRET: '{"type":"HS256","key":"***************************","claims_namespace":"p-clamis-allow","claims_map":{"x-hasura-user-id":{"path":"$$.user.id"}}}'

Comment: Thanks for the inputs, infact i tried this and used the below JSON payload for the JWT but it does not  accept the user.id. 
I get the error "\"x-hasura-user-id\" header is expected but not found" 
Payload: {
    "name": "Test",
    "user": {
        "id": "123"
    },
    "p-clamis-allow": {
        "x-hasura-allowed-roles": [
            "user","admin"
        ],
        "x-hasura-default-role": "user"
    }
}

Comment: Is there a typo in your `p-claims-allow` attribute there?

Comment: No, i was using Hasura 1.XX, i upgraded to hasura/graphql-engine:v2.0.1 and it started working

Answer (score 1):

This will work with

```
export HASURA_GRAPHQL_JWT_SECRET="{ \"type\": \"HS256\", \"key\": \"***************************\",\"claims_namespace\":\"p-claims-allow\"}"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).